# Generating .onion adresses out of public key

Tags: onion-routing

Suppose in my node.js app I have a 1024bit RSA key pair., I hashed the public key and derive .onion addres from the hash.

Is it possible to register this exact keypair and the hostname as a hidden service? and if so - how?  I assume that steps wuld be creating a hidden service folder in /var/lib/tor, placing there hostname and privateKey files, and adding this service in torrc... But where to put the public key? should I put signature of the folder? any other steps I am missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest method is to create a vanilla onion service, e.g.:

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/onion
HiddenServicePort 80
```

Then start the `tor` service, let it finish loading, then stop the `tor` service.

Now edit the file `/var/lib/tor/onion/private_key` and replace the private key in the file with the one you've generated and save the file, then start Tor.

The public key isn't needed since the private key already contains all the information that the public key does.

Now when you start the `tor` service again, you should see your custom hostname has been written to the `/var/lib/tor/onion/hostname` file (where it previously had the one Tor generated for you).

The reason I'd recommend this path is that Tor is picky about permissions on the files and folders, to ensure that only the user `tor` is running as can read the keys, so this lets `tor` create the files and folder with the right permissions for you. All you need to do is replace the contents of the `private_key` file.

The RSA private key should be stored in PEM format.

Comment: This is likely a duplicate but I couldn't find one that was specific enough to be a direct answer. If you see a duplicate of this, please flag it up.